# difference between Html.BeginForm() and ajax.beginform()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

what is the difference between `Html.BeginForm`() and `Ajax.Beginform`() in MVC3. I just want to know the scenarios where I can use `Html.BeginForm`() and where I can use `Ajax.Beginform`().

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3

Answer (score 21):

**Ajax**

1. Won't redirect the form even you do a `RedirectAction()`.
2. Will perform save , update and any modification operations asynchronously.
3. Validate the Form using `FormMethods - OnSubmit`. So you are abort the `Post`
4. This creates a form that submits its values using an asynchronous ajax request. This allows a portion of the page to be update without requiring that the entire page be refreshed.

**Html**

1. Will redirect the form.
2. Will perform operations both `Synchronously` and `Asynchronously` (With some extra code and care).
3. Html.BeginForm will always use RouteTable to detrmine the action attribute value.
4. This will create a form on the page that submits its values to the server as a synchronous HTTP request, refreshing the entire page in the process.

Answer (score 12):

**Html.BeginForm()** will create a form on the page that submits its values to the server as a synchronous HTTP request, refreshing the entire page in the process.

**Ajax.BeginForm()** creates a form that submits its values using an asynchronous ajax request. This allows a portion of the page to be update without requiring that the entire page be refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

`Html.BeginForm()` will use simple posting on page, it means your page will be refreshed when you post your form.
when `Ajax.BeginForm()` will use ajax posting on page, it means your page will not be refreshed when you post your form.

Comment: follow the link -   http://softmindit.blogspot.in/2013/07/htmlbeginform-vs-ajaxbeginform-in-mvc3.html

Answer (score 0):

@Html.BeginForm is used to post the data by full page refresh whereas @Ajax.BeginForm performs Post back function and allows some portion of Html to be reloaded rather than overall page refresh.