# Best Practice for showing Page after Post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have a View with a Form that calls a controller action Post Method to "Complete" a Package. It then needs to refresh the page its on as that contains information that will be updated, both within the view itself and also within a partial. It does use two different Controllers in different MVC Areas.

The Post works correctly and the redirect is issued, but the page is not refreshed.

I have read that instead, I should use OnSuccess within the Ajax call that calls Complete, but I thought that was for in page calls, not ones that navigate to different pages.

View Form

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Complete", "Packages", new { Area = "Core" },
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
```

{

Core(Area) Packages Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Complete(int ID)
{ 
    // Update code

    // Refresh the full page

    return RedirectToAction("Summary", new { Area = "Control", id = packageBuilder.CurrentPackage.ID });
}
```

Control (Area) Packages Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Summary(int id)
{ 
    // Get Model
    return View("Summary", model);    
}
```

Any pointers would be warmly welcomed.

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: So what is the problem, that you submit the form and the form is still populated after being submitted?

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485886/difference-between-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform as the answer below states, one forces a post back of the page, the other doesn't (designed for AJAX requests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that your page is not refreshed after you submit the form and the redirect is not issued in the browser, is that you are submitting the request over AJAX.  This is a request issued by the browser behind the scenes.

If you want to submit the form and for the page to be refreshed, I'd recommend changing your code from `Ajax.BeginForm(...` to `Html.BeginForm(...` and then it will load the page and perform the redirect as expected.

Comment: you're a star. Thanks nik0lias too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how your ajax calls are structured, but if you are using the MVC Ajax helper you can just call `location.reload(); in the OnComplete method, like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions{OnComplete = "javascriptfunction"}))
{
    //Data and submit button
}
<script>
    function javascriptfunction(){
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```