# Prevent page redirect/stay on the same page upon form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can't figure out for the life of me why this isn't working the way it should...

I've got a ASP.NET MVC5 form where there are two buttons--"Add New Product", will allow them to temporarily save all of the product data (NOT to the database) and allow them to input another information on a product; the other button, "Save Changes", will save all of those products that were added via "Add New Product".

I'm currently stuck on the "Add New Product" functionality. Currently, it's redirecting users to a new page and I can't figure out why it's still redirecting when it technically shouldn't be. Any reason why it's doing a redirect? It's going through the controller method just fine too. I just want it to stay on the same page, but currently with what I have it's getting redirected to a blank page, the exact partial view I was on.

**Javascript**

```
$("#ProductForm").submit(function () {
    // Data validation here
    if (hasErrors) {
        // Display errors to user via unobtrusive validation
    }
    else {
        var ProductViewModel = {
            'Name': $("#ItemName").val(),
            'Price': $("#ItemPrice").val(),
            // etc.
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: $("#AddProductURL").val(),
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "POST",
            data: ProductViewModel,
            success: function () {
                // Clear all fields
                $("#ProductForm").reset();
                return false; // I guess this isn't working?
            }
        });
        return false; // I guess this isn't working either?
    }
    return false; // Not working as well?
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductViewModel productVM)
{
    // Do stuff with the view model here
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Either the selector doesn't match, or the script runs before the elements are available. Do `console.log( $("#ProductForm").length )` and see what you get

Comment: @adeneo I'm getting a 1. What does that mean?

Comment: That means it should work just fine

Comment: @adeneo Well shoot, that doesn't help me...lol.

Comment: Put a console log inside the event handler, and see if it fires when you submit the form. Returning false should stop the form from submitting if the event handler is hit

Comment: @adeneo So the whole javascript method is getting fired, including the method in the controller to the very end. But inside Ajax success, I tried putting an alert there and it's not getting fired. The redirect seems to happen before success even gets hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I feel SUPER dumb. I thought I mentioned this in the original post, but I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 and I didn't realize how relevant it was. I'll edit my post in a moment to reflect it.

There's a difference between @Html.BeginForm and @Ajax.BeginForm which I found out through this Stack Overflow answer: [difference between Html.BeginForm() and ajax.beginform()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485886/difference-between-html-beginform-and-ajax-beginform)

The very top bullet point for @Ajax.BeginForm answered my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#ProductForm").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
// Data validation here
if (hasErrors) {
    // Display errors to user via unobtrusive validation
}
... rest of the code
```

Comment: I'm getting some strange error...it's showing up in the log when I hit var ProductViewModel: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined at HTMLFormElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.js:626), <anonymous>:52:78)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.js:5109)
at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.10.2.js:4780)

Comment: `return false` combines `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` in jQuery, so the OP is already doing this